# Проблемы vue css

Tags: css, vue.js

Всем привет!Сделал приложение на vue.Выкладываю проект на github pages и начинаются проблемы с css,а главный фокус в том , что некоторые стили работают некоторые нет.
Опыта работы с вебпак мало и поэтому прошу вас мне помочь ) Ссылка на webpack 
https://github.com/ronin1991/cats/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Попробуй в секции стилей написать так `<style scoped>`. Возможно, какие-то стили из одного компонента перекрывают стили из другого.

Comment: Попробовал , не подходит решение